# Case statement label in C

Tags: c

My below code doesn't print Hi, instead it runs and prints Bye

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum 
{ 
    RED, 
    GREEN, 
    BLUE 
} color;

int main(void) {
    color chosenColor = GREEN;
    printf("val %d\n",chosenColor);
    int x=1;
    switch(x)
    {
        case RED:
        GREEN:
        printf("HI");
        break;

        default:
        printf("BYE");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output
val 1
BYE

But if I modify it as below and add case in front of GREEN, it prints Hi

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum 
{ 
    RED, 
    GREEN, 
    BLUE 
} color;

int main(void) {
    color chosenColor = GREEN;
    printf("val %d\n",chosenColor);
    int x=1;
    switch(x)
    {
        case RED:
        case GREEN:
        printf("HI");
        break;

        default:
        printf("BYE");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output
val 1
HI

Can someone tell why is this even happening in first program, is something wrong there?

Comment: `case` lables have to come with `case` keyword. It is the syntax. Without it it is just a label (for `goto` for instance)

Comment: Do not tag C++ for C questions. Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: If I use a number there without case it throws error, so it means if I use any english word there followed by : , it will be getting treated as a goto label? And if I use number followed by :, it throws error. Can you pls help explain this too?

Comment: `goto` labels can't be numbers. They must follow the C identifier naming rules.

Comment: @Lundin: OP is expecting `GREEN` to have value 1; that and where enumerations start by default is not at issue in their question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No, it would seem that is precisely their problem, since there is no reason why `case RED` would be executed in the first example. If they knew that enums start with 0 then why involve `case RED` to begin with, when x is 1.

Comment: @Lundin I simply wanted case to go over GREEN in first example which instead made it a goto label, in example 2 I just added a case: in front of it and it worked. I know how enum works, that's why to show I have added a print as well above the switch.

Comment: @Anime Fair enough. Though you could as well have written `x = GREEN;`

Answer (score 1):

`GREEN:` without `case` does not form a `case`-labeled statement for `switch`. It declares `GREEN` to be a label for `goto` statement. It has no effect on the switch.

Turning up warnings in your compiler might produce a warning message that the label is not used. Generally, you should request lots of warnings and elevate warnings to errors. With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

Comment: If I use a number there without case it throws error, so it means if I use any english word there followed by : , it will be getting treated as a goto label? And if I use number followed by :, it throws error. Can you pls help explain this too?

Comment: @Anime: The compiler does not care about English words. A label for a plain labeled statement can be any identifier. An identifier is a string of characters that is not a keyword of the C language; that starts with `_`, a letter a-z, a letter A-Z, or certain other characters specified in C 2018 6.4.2.1 1; and that is followed by zero or more of those characters and digits 0-9. A decimal numeral is not such an identifier, so it cannot be a label.

Comment: @Anime `case` can be followed by any integer constant, including numbers or enums. A pure goto label however, follows the same naming conventions as any other identifier (variables, functions etc).

Answer (score 0):

- `RED` being the first item in an enum list, equals value `0`. So `case RED:` will never get called when you do `int x=1; switch(x)`
- `GREEN:` in the first example is a useless `goto` label which fills no purpose.
- `case GREEN:` in the second example checks for value 1 and `x` is indeed 1 so the `case GREEN:` gets executed. The `case RED:` above it is irrelevant.